# Creating network from adjacency matrix using weights on networkx

Tags: graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

Here is my question: from a HMM model I created, I want to create a network using the transition matrix (with the probability to go from a state to another) as an adjacency matrix. There are no 0s in this matrix, neither on the diagonal, because you can go from state 1 to state 1 again.
How can I be sure that the network created is actually using the weights (the values in the transition matrix) to create communities?

I'm using the following code:

```
import community
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(tm, parallel_edges=False, create_using=None)

# Relabel nodes
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {i: f"node_{i}" for i in G.nodes})

# Compute partition
partition = community.best_partition(G)

# Get a set of the communities
communities = set(partition.values())

# Create a dictionary mapping community number to nodes within that community
communities_dict = {c: [k for k, v in partition.items() if v == c] for c in communities}
communities_dict
```

and the output makes sense: 5 communities (0 to 4) grouping 25 nodes (from 0 to 24)

```
{0: ['node_0', 'node_1', 'node_14', 'node_17'],
 1: ['node_5', 'node_10', 'node_11', 'node_12'],
 2: ['node_2', 'node_20', 'node_24'],
 3: ['node_3', 'node_8', 'node_9', 'node_15', 'node_18', 'node_22'],
 4: ['node_4',   'node_6',   'node_7',  'node_13', 'node_16', 'node_19', 'node_21', 'node_23']}
```

I noticed a post here on stack overflow in which they used

```
partition = community.best_partition(G, weight='weights')
```

I tried to implement it, and the results are awful: each node is a community (for a total of 25 communities on 25 nodes).

My question is: am I doing good with the first code? Or the correct one is the other one which return bad communities?

Comment: "How can I be sure that the network created is actually using the weights"  a) Print out the weights and check them. b) write a unit test

Comment: It seems you might not have assigned any weights to your edges. Wouldn't that be a prerequisite for the best_partition() method?

Comment: I created it from a Numpy matrix, in which each element should be a weight, but I didn't assign any weight to the nodes. Is there a way to assign weights to the node from the matrix?